# Cannot delete __jb_old___ file

Tags: windows, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

It seems like WebStorm created a file `login.component.ts___jb_old___` and I can't delete it or move it.

I've gone into settings and turned off safe write, and restarted WebStorm, but I can't delete the file, which is making me unable to run my docker container.

Doing an `ls -ll` prints

`-rw-r----- 1 Uknown+User Unknown+User 2308 Feb 6 11:29 login.component.ts___jb_old___`

All of the other files in the directory have the correct permissions and are owned by me.

I'm on Windows and I am the only user on the computer and set as Admin, I've opened an Admin command prompt and still get access denied when trying to change permissions of the file or delete the file.

When I open File Explorer to try and change it through the windows gui it tells me `You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.`

Any ideas on how I can delete this file?

Comment: try re-booting - does the issue persist?

Comment: 1) Reboot first; 2) If still the same (which would be very weird) -- try making yourself an owner (`File Properties in Explorer | Security | Advanced`)

Comment: @lena and LazyOne thanks, I downloaded UnlockIt and tried with that, which also required a reboot. But now the file is gone thankfully! Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

You shoud close your webstorm app.

I delete it success but created again when i refresh directory.

I restart the PC then this problem resolved...

Answer (score 1):

**A working fix.**

IntelliJ 2019.2.2 w/ PyCharm (Latest release)

After updating to 2019.2.2 I was having this error as well. The problem I was facing was on running webpack-dev-server.

Found the recommendation to disable 'Safe writing' - which resolved my issue.

**Settings > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, but am I sabotaging myself in the long run?!  TBD.